# Using `GETDATE()` Redshift function with psycopg2 execute_values

Tags: amazon-redshift, psycopg2, bulkinsert

Is it possible to use the Redshift function `GETDATE()` along with `psycopg2.extras.execute_values` when inserting many rows?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={
            'ExampleID' : list(range(1,6)),
            'NumericField' : list(range(44,49)),
            'UpdateTime' : list('GETDATE()' for i in range(5))
            })

conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname=database, host=host, port=5439, user=username, password=password)
cursor = conn.cursor()
v = df.to_records(index=False).tolist()

q = sql.SQL('INSERT INTO tblexample (ExampleID, NumericField, UpdateTime) VALUES %s')
execute_values(cursor, q.as_string(cursor), v)
conn.commit()
```

Unfortunately, this raises an exception:
`psycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "GETDATE()"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized that since `GETDATE()` exists in Redshift but not Postgresql, it's unlikely to work in this case.  Instead, used `str(datetime.datetime.now())`.